# How we can see SElinux policies running on a centos system??

Tags: centos, selinux

I am given with an assignment that how we can see what selinux policies are running on a system(centos), as i am a new and dont know about the system

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question implies lack of basic research.

Answer (score 2):

As there are several approaches to using SELinux and you didn't provide any information which one you are using, I'm guessing that you are interested in what services and programs run confined, i.e. restricted by SELinux.

- `ps -efZ` will provide insight into which process is labeled with what SELinux type.
- `semanage` provides information on what type labels are supposed to be assigned where, what types are available, which ones are set to permissive and much more.

Regarding what your system's default policy is, you have to check your OS vendor's documentation as this varies from distro to distro.